# Why can't I add an xml node to the Header and Footer sections in Word Document 2007?

Tags: ms-word, docx, xmlnodelist

I am facing strange problem in Word Document-2007. I have created a Word Document Template and I create XML nodes for that template to print repeating data, for that I keep all the XML nodes on Word Document using Developer Tab it is working fine. Because that template creates more than 6 pages, my client needs to show the the header and footer section. I put the XML node on Header part section, but it won't print that node value.  If I put static text on Header section it should show dynamically, but it doesn't.  Why is this?.

**Edit**

```
1 . I have create custom xmlnodes like below 

      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <xs:schema id="WorkOrders" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
        xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XSDSchema1.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="Cfield1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Cfield2" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:schema>
```

when i save the file it save **Customnode.xsd**

2.Than i added these custom nodes in Word document template using Developr tag --> add schema--> select XSD file and then place the Nodes on template.

1. Now, i have bind the data using vb.net like below.

   ```
   Dim Traveler As Object
   Dim Travelerdoc As Object
   Dim myxmlnode As Object
    Traveler = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Travelerdoc = Traveler.Documents.Add("Documentpath/WordDocument.doc")
   For Each myxmlnode In Travelerdoc.XMLNodes
     If myxmlnode.BaseName = "Cfield1" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text ="Hello"
     If myxmlnode.BaseName = "Cfield2" Then myxmlnode.Range.Text = "Word Document"
     if(totalrecords<=5)
     myxmlnode.Range.Select()
     Travelerdoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertRowsBelow()
      End If
   Next
   ```

Comment: Could you please add the resulting word document **and** the code you used to generate it ? I don't really get what you want. I guess you're using macros as you're speaking of **developper tab**

Comment: Hi edi,thank you so much for replay and i'm sorry for late response because i was in sick leave..,actually i have create custom xml nodes using VB.net and then add those xml nodes to word document template.After adding those i have bind the data find the xml node and print the data .. I updated my code please check it once.

Comment: I don't know how to use the Developper Tab of Word, and am unable to duplicate your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all for giving reply to me .. anyway finally i resolve my issue ... Thanks.

Here i fallow the solution...

```
        Dim rng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range
        Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
        Dim headertext As String

        For Each wordSection As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section In Travelerdoc.Sections

       rng = wordSection.Headers(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
       rng.Font.Size = 14
            rng.InsertAfter(vbTab & vbTab & "WO : " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("wo").ToString())

          Next
```

Comment: Hi Bluefeet actually i have post for my own question that's why i post like thank you message...

Comment: I would suggest coming back and accepting this answer when the system will allow you to do so!

Comment: How is it possible , it accepted my vote for my own answer...! i wonder .. anyway Thank you..