# Inserting values OK in mysql database i check box state is checked

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, checkbox

You may try to state that this is duplicate, but as far as i haved search the stack overflow and some search engines, i have realized that none of them answers my problem, so here is my code:

This is for my save button

```
If chkPic.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Insert into tbl_employee(Picture) values (Ok) where LastName = '" & txtLastName.Text & "' AND FirstName = '" & txtFirstName.Text & "' AND MiddleName = '" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
        End If
```

This is for my update button

```
If chkPic.Checked Then
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set Picture = '& Ok &' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "' and FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' and MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        Else
            myr.Close()
            mycom.CommandText = "Update tbl_employee set Picture = '' where LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "' and FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "' and MiddleName='" & txtMiddleName.Text & "' "
            myr = mycom.ExecuteReader
            myr.Close()
        End If
```

And i would also like to consider how to read its data in my lost focus event, which i coded as:

```
        If myr(75) = "Ok" Then
        chkPic.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
    Else
        chkPic.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
    End If
```

Any help please anyone.. Thanks

Comment: We won't try to state that this is duplicate because there is no question here. You gave us some code; that's great, code is often missing in questions. However, what is your *problem*?

Comment: @Amadan thanks for that, my question is when i checked my checkboxes, the word Ok dont insert in my database

Comment: You don't need the `&` symbol in `"Update tbl_employee set Picture = '& Ok &'...` Remove that

Comment: How about in the Save part, i still cant get my data in my database when i click the save button

Comment: for _save_ part, try `"Insert into tbl_employee(Picture) values ('Ok')...`

Comment: The word Ok still wont go in my database :( @Jonjongot

Comment: How many column in your `tbl_employee`? check the constraint. does  `null` value allowed in other columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65936/discussion-between-ako-ci-divine-and-jonjongot).